# How do I evaluate a string as a logical argument?

Tags: python, loops, robotframework

I'm working on a nestable For Loop in Python for Robot Framework. My goal is to mimic 100% of the functionality of the original, so I need to be able to break the For Loop if certain conditions are met. My solution to this is with a custom keyword that is evaluated a little differently in the Python code: `exit_if`.

`exit_if` takes one argument, a string, and returns one argument for processing, a Boolean. I'd like to send it a string like `'$var1 == $var2'` (I've already solved the problem of requiring parentheses around custom variable names created within the For Loop from Robot Framework), have `exit_if` evaluate the string as it would any Boolean expression, and return `True` if the expression evaluates to `True`, and `False` if the expression evaluates to `False`.

An easy solution to this is to have `exit_if` take three arguments: `var1`, `operator`, and `var2`. Then, in a switch statement, evaluate the variables based on the operator. However, this seems unnecessarily clunky and inefficient, so I'd like to find a more elegant solution.

After Googling around (it's possible that my Google searches were parameterized incorrectly), I found nothing that would do what I'm trying to ask this program to do, so, given that this is a coding question that can benefit future programmers, I turned to this site. How can I accomplish the effects of the three-parameter solution with a single parameter and no/minimum switch/if statements?

EDIT: I apologize for the brevity of the original post, I was rushed out of the office in the process of asking this question.

Robot Framework interacts with my For Loop by sending a very long list of cells of information in a Framework-like language that my code then processes and turns into the format required for `BuiltIn().run_keywords`. In Robot Framework, this format looks like so (simple version):

```
For Loop    IN RANGE    0    3   INDEX0
...     \\  Log to Console  INDEX0
...     \\  Run Keyword If  INDEX0 == 1  Log to Console  one
```

Robot Framework processes this as a single line of cells, like so (cells are separated by |):

```
For Loop|IN RANGE|0|2|INDEX0|\\|Log to Console|INDEX0|\\|Run Keyword If|INDEX0 == 1|Log to Console|one
```

My code converts these cells into a list of strings.

```
['For Loop','IN RANGE','0','2','INDEX0','\\','Log to Console','INDEX0','\\','Run Keyword If','INDEX0 == 1','Log to Console','one']
```

Then, the code used to format it for use each loop iteration by `BuiltIn().run_keywords()`. So, on iteration 2 (INDEX0 = 1):

```
kwords = ['Log to Console','1','AND','Run Keyword If','1 == 1','Log to Console','one']
BuiltIn().run_keywords(*kwords)
```

That system being too limited to the built-in capabilities of `Run Keywords`, I created a mirror version of it that I can control. Its functionality is identical to `Run Keywords`, but it is called by `self._run_keywords(*kwords)`.

As it stands now, that code won't run. I'm trying to create code that will process the `1 == 1` and pass it to some keyword. Given my current goal is to allow the user to specify breakpoints in the loop, I created a function called `exit_if`. `exit_if` will (eventually) receive an argumentative input in the form of a string (like the one above, though not necessarily in the same syntax), decide if the conditions are right to exit the for loop, and exit the for loop. I want it to return a Boolean for verification purposes, and because I'm not entirely sure how `exit_if` will interact with the rest of the file yet.

I already knew of a very clunky way to do this. Take the input (`1 == 1`), use string parsing to find the operator and variables, use a switch statement to decide which comparison to do, do the comparison, and (possibly) return the value to the rest of the loop so that it can stop the loop.

Thanks to Kindall, I now have an easier way to do this with a dictionary and `operator`, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution along the lines of the following:

```
def exit_if(argument_string):
    if argument_string:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Obviously, feeding an `if` statement an existing string always results in `True`, but I was hoping to be able to cast the string as something or apply a function to it to turn it into a Boolean statement. If this isn't possible and I need to go the clunky way, that's fine. Speed and beauty aren't requirements, but it was worth asking.

Comment: Have you found the `eval` function?

Comment: why wouldnt you just make it take a bool ? `exit_if(a==b)`

Comment: In Python you can pass functions as arguments to other functions, so rather than inventing some micro-expression language why not do that? E.g. have your `exit_if` take a function of two arguments, and then call that function?

Comment: `eval('$var1 == $var2')` would throw a syntax error.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Because it's a tool for Robot Framework written in Python. The parameter that I CAN pass it is a string, based on how Robot Framework works.

Comment: @Prune I just did, but I am now away from the code. I'll attempt it as soon as is possible. That looks like the most likely solution at the moment.

Comment: @HåkenLid Done.

Comment: @Iguananaut See my answer to Joran and the new information in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `operator` module and a dictionary.

```
import operator

ops = {"==": operator.eq,
       "!=": operator.ne,
       "<":  operator.lt,
       "<=": operator.le,
       ">":  operator.gt,
       ">=": operator.ge}

def compare(a, op, b):
    return ops[op](a, b)

assert compare(3, "<", 4)
```

Looking up your variable names and passing in their values, I'll leave to you.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind as a strict upgrade to my first approach, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'll edit the question to include a better example as soon as I get to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regular expressions** to solve this.

```
import re

varSet = {'var1' : 1, 'var2' : 2 } #Dictionary for your variables

def exit_if(stringPassed):
    #(.*) - any character and its occurence
    pattern = re.compile(r'(.*) (.*) (.*)')
    #Looks for the matches, result.group(0) shows the result
    result  = pattern.match(stringPassed) 

    firstVariable  = varSet[result.group(1)] #'var1'
    operatorUsed   = result.group(2) #'=='
    secondVariable = varSet[result.group(3)] #'var2'

    if operatorUsed == '==':
        return firstVariable == secondVariable
    elif operatorUsed == '!=':
        return firstVariable != secondVariable
    elif operatorUsed == '<':
        return firstVariable < secondVariable
    elif operatorUsed == '<=':
        return firstVariable <= secondVariable
    elif operatorUsed == '>':
        return firstVariable > secondVariable
    elif operatorUSed == '>=':
        return firstVariable >= secondVariable
    else:
        print ('Some kind of error')

#Given that the pattern is always '$var1 == $var2'
print exit_if('var1 == var2') #prints False
print exit_if('var1 < var2') #prints True
```

More about re module:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html